# Fuzzy Matching with Strings containing numbers

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison, stringdist

I am trying approximate matches between the reference and the target strings.

I have tried adist and stringdist in R with the various distances available.

While the algorithms do a good job of matching strings with only alphabets it fails to match strings where there are numbers and special characters (%, etc) are present.

How can this case be handled?

The following is my code.

```
library(stringdist)

dist.name <- outer(tolower(WW_name),tolower(Px_name),
                   stringdist::stringdist, method = "lcs")

# We now take the pairs with the minimum distance
min.name<-apply(dist.name, 1, min)

match.s1.s2<-NULL

chk <- function(x){
  s2.i<-match(min.name[x],dist.name[x,])
  s1.i<-x
  match.s1.s2<-rbind(data.frame(s2.i=s2.i,s1.i=s1.i,WWname=WW_lookup[s1.i],
                                Pxname=Px_lookup[s2.i],
                                adist=min.name[x]),match.s1.s2)
  return(match.s1.s2)
}

outDf <- lapply(1:nrow(dist.name),FUN = chk)

outDf <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, outDf)
```

Examples where the match is not right below -

[image]

**Pxname is the match from algorithm | MappedPxName is mapped manually**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a brief example where the matching doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Very interesting problem, but please do provide more data. What strings? What code are you using to find the distance/similarity?

Comment: @AllanCameron added examples

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I cannot make the data public. I have added an example to the post. Hope this gives u some idea.

Comment: That's a good start. Can you make your data snippet copy/pastable? You can always make up some entries that mimic your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. Since you cannot share your data, what I can do for you is limited. But my hope is that the following will help you to some extant. I think the challenge here is to convert numbers to written numbers. This is something we can handle with the english package. I created two vectors (i.e., WWname and PXname). I also created my own function called `myfun`. This handles some string manipulation like converting % to percent, and converting numbers to written numbers. I used this function and created two data frames (i.e., ww and px).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(english)
library(stringi)
library(stringdist)

WWname <- c("Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g", "Excellence Dark 78% COCOA 100G",
            "ZDEL Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g", "Excellence Dark 50% Cocoa 100g")

PXname <- c("Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g", "Excellence Dark 80% Cocoa 200g",
            "ZDEL Excellence Dark 80% Cocoa 100g", "ZDEL Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g",
            "ZDEL Excellence Dark 78% Cocoa 100g", "Excellence Dark 78% Cocoa 100g",
            "Excellence Dark 50% Cocoa 100g")

myfun <- function(myvec) {

  sub(x = myvec, pattern = "%", replacement = " percent") %>%
  sub(pattern = "(?<=[0-9])g|G", replacement = " grams", perl = T) %>%
  tolower %>% 
  stri_split_regex(pattern = "\\s") %>% 
  enframe %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  mutate(word = if_else(grepl(x = value, pattern = "[0-9]+"),
                        as.character(english(as.numeric(value))),
                        value)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(string = paste0(word, collapse = " ")) -> out
  return(out)
}

# Convert numbers to alphabets abd create new strings.

ww <- myfun(myvec = WWname)
px <- myfun(myvec = PXname)

# Calculate distance.
mymat <- stringdistmatrix(a = ww$string, b = px$string, method = "lcs")

rownames(mymat) <- WWname
colnames(mymat) <- PXname

# Check if there is any non-match.
mymat %>%
as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
rownames_to_column(var = "WWname") %>%
pivot_longer(cols = -WWname, names_to = "PXname", values_to = "ranking") %>% 
group_by(WWname) %>%
mutate(check = if_else(any(ranking == 0),
                       TRUE,
                       FALSE)) -> out
```

Now we check matching patterns.

```
filter(out, check == TRUE) %>%
slice(which.min(ranking))

  WWname                              PXname                              ranking check
  <chr>                               <chr>                                 <dbl> <lgl>
1 Excellence Dark 50% Cocoa 100g      Excellence Dark 50% Cocoa 100g            0 TRUE 
2 Excellence Dark 78% COCOA 100G      Excellence Dark 78% Cocoa 100g            0 TRUE 
3 Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g      Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g            0 TRUE 
4 ZDEL Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g ZDEL Excellence Dark 85% Cocoa 100g       0 TRUE
```

If we want to check non-match, we can do the following. This will return the shortest mismatch. In this case, there is no match.

```
filter(out, check == FALSE) %>%
slice(which.min(ranking))
```